# 500 (Internal Server Error) with Smart Capture Form

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture

I have previously built forms and had no issue. With this newest form I've built, I am receiving a 500 (Internal Server Error) when attempting to submit the form on PC browsers in IE & Chrome (within Windows 8 & 10).

Weirdly enough I receive no errors and can successfully submit the form on browsers running on a Mac.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: You get those errors when there's a problem with the server-side code.  Is the page getting what it's needing from the source URL? Hard to tell from your question, since you didn't include any code.  Likely has nothing to do with the browser.